# Chrome DevTools [chrome://inspect] : 404 Not Found The resource could not be found

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I used "chrome://inspect" for a few days. Everything was fine. Today, for some reason, when I click "inspect" the result is "404 Not Found The resource could not be found."

[image: Chrome DevTools]

**What could be the reason for this ?**

I was able to find only this topic: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=329979

I guess the drivers are OK if the device appears ? I`m able to transfer files, to "focus tab" or "close tab" and "reload" but i can't "inspect".

Chrome Version: 37.0.2062.124 m

DevTools URL : chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_rev/@180870/devtools.html?&remoteFrontend=true&dockSide=undocked&toolbarColor=rgba(230,230,230,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)

Edit:

I tink this comment is important so...

> A bug was opened in the Google tracker: [Link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=418943) Please star it! Remember that you don't have to add a comment to it if you don't have new information :)

by MM

Edit 2:

> DevTools are actually broken for ANY kind of Android devices, regardless device's version, Chrome version or OS. URLs of such kinds - http://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_rev/@180870/devtools.html - that must return DevTools code - now returns 404. That could be fixed by Google without any change in the Chrome code, it's completely server-side problem.

by vrid...@gmail.com at [bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=418943#c10)

Edit 3: At this time  http://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_rev/@180870/devtools.html is OK but slow. I realy cant get why I need usb driver to send data over the internet... to this page just to debug.

Comment: Might be a bug in latest chrome... Getting same bug here dude
I'll reference this in a bug report

Comment: I get the same problem. Is it possible to get older chrome version?

Comment: A bug was opened in the Google tracker: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=418943 Please star it! Remember that you don't have to add a comment to it if you don't have new information :)

Comment: Its already working for me

Comment: they said they wont fix the bug

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem, but it was caused by chosen `AOSP WebView` instead of `Chrome Stable` at `Developer Options > WebView Implementation`. If you do not have `Chrome Stable` option available, then try to install Chrome and check again.

Comment: This was my issue too, thanks.  So strange that AOSP's Webview doesn't support debugging..oh well.

Comment: Same issue on lineage os.

Comment: I don't have Chrome or Chromium. And a few months back I was debugging fine with the Android System WebView (currently ver 92.0.4515.144). Is this the same as AOSP WebView?

Comment: @Carolus I am not sure how it looks like now, maybe it is somehow unified. I know that previously the AOSP WebView was used in a custom roms.

Comment: Yeah, that is very likely.  This device ships with some Google-free rom. And my setup worked fine today with some other Android device that has `Chrome Stable`. I was surprised because my Google-free device used to work fine. Maybe some updates changed something...

Answer (score 9):

Just had the same issue. VPN was on, turnning it off fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

That was a cloud storage glitch. Things have reverted to normal since then.

Answer (score 0):

After updating chrome version on Android device worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

This still occurs and workaround is to open chrome://inspect and click on inspect link under Remote target assuming the command `node --inspect server.js` is already hit.

Answer (score -2):

Workaround:

1. disable chrome updates. Instructions: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/stop-automatic-chrome-updates-windows/
2. uninstall latest Chrome on desktop.
3. install previous version:  (I used slimjet: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php)
4. Open chrome://inspect/#devices url and choose inspect-fallback instead of inspect.

---